# How to process a list of files with SLURM

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, slurm

I'm new to SLURM. I want to process a list of files `assembled_reads/*.sorted.bam` in parallel. With the code below, however only one process is being used over and over again.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=****
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=24
#SBATCH --partition=short
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --array=1-100
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=16000
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=****@***.edu
srun hostname

for FILE in assembled_reads/*.sorted.bam; do
  echo ${FILE}
  OUTFILE=$(basename ${FILE} .sorted.bam).raw.snps.indels.g.vcf
  PLDY=$(awk -F "," '$1=="$FILE"{print $4}' metadata.csv)
  PLDYNUM=$( [[$PLDY = "haploid" ]] && echo "1" || echo "2")

  srun java -Djava.io.tmpdir="tmp" -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
  -R scaffs_HAPSgracilaria92_50REF.fasta \
  -T HaplotypeCaller \
  -I ${${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}} \
  --emitRefConfidence GVCF \
  -ploidy $PLDYNUM \
  -nt 1 \
  -nct 24 \
  -o $OUTFILE
  sleep 1 # pause to be kind to the scheduler
done
```

Comment: See damienfrancois's answer below. You could probably use a wrapper script that determines the number of files and then submits the script shown in his answer using the `--array` parameter to specify the number of file determined in your wrapper script.

Comment: You should use a workflow manager that can submit to SLURM. I would recommend [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/). SLURM docs [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#slurm) and [here](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-executor). If you try to do this solely with SLURM, your analysis pipeline will quickly grow too complex to manage and/or you will destroy performance on your cluster.

Comment: Also a quick Google search will show example Nextflow pipelines that run GATK, some might even come with basic SLURM configs already. Some are listed [here](https://github.com/nextflow-io/awesome-nextflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a job array but are not using it. You should replace the for-loop with an indexing of the files based on the slurm job array id:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=****
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=24
#SBATCH --partition=short
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --array=0-99
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=16000
#SBATCH --mail-type=FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=****@***.edu
srun hostname
FILES=(assembled_reads/*.sorted.bam)    
FILE=${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}

echo ${FILE}
OUTFILE=$(basename ${FILE} .sorted.bam).raw.snps.indels.g.vcf
PLDY=$(awk -F "," '$1=="$FILE"{print $4}' metadata.csv)
PLDYNUM=$( [[$PLDY = "haploid" ]] && echo "1" || echo "2")

srun java -Djava.io.tmpdir="tmp" -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
  -R scaffs_HAPSgracilaria92_50REF.fasta \
  -T HaplotypeCaller \
  -I ${${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}} \
  --emitRefConfidence GVCF \
  -ploidy $PLDYNUM \
  -nt 1 \
  -nct 24 \
  -o $OUTFILE
```

Just make sure to adapt the value of `--array` to be equal to the number of files to process.

Comment: Wow. I remember using LSF job arrays a few times and having to include consecutive numbers in the file names. This is much more flexible!

Comment: With this that same file is being passed as input to for each iteration. I takes a couple days for the job to finish running the reason I'm responding so late

Comment: I think this is slightly wrong, the --array=0-99 will actually process the 100 files. ${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} will then properly be 0-99 and index all 100 files. Otherwise it will leave off the first one!